# Django: Getting render_to_response to accept bytes rather than html on disk

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have an html file which is generated on-the-fly, and that I don't want to save to disk. Normally in Django, to get the html to the user, you use:

```
return render_to_response('foo.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

However, I have no `foo.html` on disk, I have a `bytes` string. How do I get Django to render a string rather than a file? (Note: The generated file has `{% block content %}` and so on that Django needs to interpret.

Using python3.4 and Django 1.8.

*At cyphase's suggestion:* I did the following:

```
my_template = Template(byte_string)
return HttpResponse(my_template.render(RequestContext(request)))
```

Comment: It doesn't look like that error you added is related to the question. Try to isolate it.

Comment: What version of Django did you get it to work on?

Comment: I didn't test it; but it should be working :). And again, the error does not appear to be about templates, though I'm not claiming that definitively. Try to isolate the issue; try using `render_to_response()` as you normally would to see if the error goes away.

Comment: It does go away when I use `render_to_response` and an html file.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: No. But I've posted everything that is relevant. I'll try to get your method to work, it seems it's not far from the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Template

def your_view(...):
    # Do stuff

    yourtemplate = Template(your_template_string)

    content = yourtemplate.render(context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    # content_type and status are the same as would be passed
    # to render() or render_to_response().
    return HttpResponse(content, content_type=None, status=None)
```

Ideally someone would implement a `render_to_response()` that takes a string or file-like object.

Comment: Got: `'SafeText' object has no attribute 'get'` from: `/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py in process_response, line 31`. I disabled the clickjacking middleware and got the same error. Are we on the same django version?

Comment: Can you add an edit to your question (don't modify it, add a section below the current question) that shows a bit of your code and the full traceback?

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @NickThompson, I've added another attempt; take a look.

Comment: I suspect that won't work either, since the return type is incorrect. See my edits. Still, you put me on the right track here; really appreciate your help.

Comment: Doh! It's returning a rendered template, not an HttpResponse. Duh.. hold on.

Comment: @NickThompson, try it again :P.